# How to convert any number to a clojure.lang.Ratio type in Clojure?

Tags: math, clojure, rational-numbers, inexact-arithmetic

In Scheme I can do:

```
#;> (numerator 1/3)
1
#;> (denominator 1/3)
3
```

In Clojure I can do something similar:

```
user=> (numerator 1/3)
1
user=> (denominator 1/3)
3
```

But in Scheme I can do:

```
#;> (numerator 0.3)
3.0
```

and it is not possible in Clojure:

```
user=> (numerator 0.3)

ClassCastException java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Ratio  clojure.core/numerator (core.clj:3306)
```

How can I convert a Double (or actually any kind of number) into a clojure.lang.Ratio?

In Scheme we have also `inexact->exact` what would be something like "double to ratio" in Clojure, but I can't find anything similar to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ooh, I know this one!

```
user=> (rationalize 0.3)
3/10
user=> (numerator (rationalize 0.3))
3
```

But the OP points out that this doesn't work for all numbers:

```
user=> (numerator (rationalize 1))
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Ratio  clojure.core/numerator (core.clj:3306)
```

see his Java interop workaround in his answer.

---

[edit] OP here:

Here is a more generic solution:

```
user=> (numerator (clojure.lang.Numbers/toRatio (rationalize 1)))
1
user=> (numerator (clojure.lang.Numbers/toRatio (rationalize 0.3)))
3
user=> (numerator (clojure.lang.Numbers/toRatio (rationalize 1/3)))
1
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work for every number, see: user=> (numerator (rationalize 1))

ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Ratio  clojure.core/numerator (core.clj:3306)

Comment: You are right. That seems unfortunate - I wonder if it is intended that (rationalize 1) returns a Long?

Comment: It seems to be a performance hit, but it is a weird behavior.

Comment: `(rational? 3)` returns `true`, but `(numerator 3)` blows up. Can't be right.

Comment: Where is @Rich Hickey? :)

Comment: Looks like a bug and I've found no evidence of it already being reported. IMO the `numerator` should be fixed, since integers are also rational numbers by definition of the latter. "Type-safe-me", however, tells me that `rationalize` should always return an instance of `Ratio`. Huh.